# RuntimeError: Model class users.models.User doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: python, django

I am having trouble finding the solution for the error posted above for a long time. I looked at several of other similar questions but could not figure it out. I really appreciate if anyone could point me to the right direction.
The exact error is the following:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x10473e840>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/@Python_project/webservice/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "~/@Python_project/webservice/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "~/@Python_project/webservice/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "~/@Python_project/webservice/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "~/@Python_project/webservice/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "~/@Python_project/webservice/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "~/@Python_project/webservice/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 120, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "~/@Python_project/webservice/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 24, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "~/@Python_project/webservice/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 26, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "~/@Python_project/webservice/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 47, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "~/@Python_project/webservice/venv/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "~/@Python_project/webservice/applications/users/admin.py", line 1, in <module>
    from applications.users import models
  File "~/@Python_project/webservice/applications/users/models.py", line 38, in <module>
    class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
  File "~/Desktop/@Python_project/webservice/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 95, in __new__
    "INSTALLED_APPS." % (module, name)
RuntimeError: Model class applications.users.models.User doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

Here is my code:

### Note that my "users" application is under "applications" directory that is located in the project root directory where manage.py is located.

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    "imagekit_cropper",
    "bootstrap4",
    "bootstrap_datepicker_plus",
    "applications.events.apps.EventsConfig",
    "applications.users.apps.CustomUsersConfig",
]
```

---

urls.py in the same directory as settings.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("applications.events.urls"), name="event"),
    path("accounts/", include("applications.users.urls")),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

---

applications/users/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from applications.users import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

app_name = "users"

urlpatterns = [
    #path("login/?next=/<str:next_path>/", views.login, name="login"),
    path("login/", views.login, name="login"),
    path("logout/", auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name="logout"),
    path("signup/", views.signup, name="signup"),
]
```

---

applications/users/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib import auth
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from applications.users import models
# Create your views here.
def signup(request):
    #account_form = models.CustomUserCreationForm()
    return render(request, "users/user_signup.html", {"account_form": account_form})

def login(request, **kwargs):
    redirect_to = request.GET.get('next', "events:retrieve_eventboard")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # First get the username and password supplied
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        # Django's built-in authentication function:
        user = auth.authenticate(email=email, password=password)
        # If we have a user
        if user:
            # Check if the account is active
            if user.is_active:
                # Log in the user.
                auth.login(request, user)
                # Send the user back to some page.
                #print("Login success")
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(redirect_to))
            else:
                # If account is not active:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("users:login"))
        else:
            #print("Someone tried to login and failed.")
            #print("They used email: {} and password: {}".format(email, password))
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("users:login"))
    else:
        # Nothing has been provided for username or password.
            return render(request, "users/user_login.html")


def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
```

---

applications/users/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin
from datetime import datetime
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class UserAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, is_staff, is_superuser):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given username, email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The email address must be set')
        username = email.split("@")[0]
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, username=username, is_staff=is_staff,
                          is_superuser=is_superuser, date_joined=datetime.now())
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        #request.session.modified = True
        return user

    def create_user(self, email=None, password=None):
        print("create_user()")
        return self._create_user(email=email, password=password, is_staff=False,
                                 is_superuser=False)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        print("create_superuser()")
        return self._create_user(email=email, password=password, is_staff=True,
                                 is_superuser=True)


#Define a table here
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(default="", max_length=30)
    #self_introduction = models.CharField(default="", max_length=280)
    #watch_list = models.
    #join_list =#

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False,
                                   help_text='Designates whether the user is a team staff.')

    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False,
                                        help_text='Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.')

    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=None, help_text="Time when the user account is created.")

    #Tell Django that this User uses UserManager instead of the default BaseUserManager
    objects = UserAccountManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

---

applications/users/apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class CustomUsersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'applications.users'
    label = "users"
```

---

Also one thing that I think might be a clue to this error is that, when I change ""applications.users.apps.CustomUsersConfig" in INSTALLED_APP to "users", the error changed to

```
"RuntimeError: Model class applications.users.models.User doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS."
```

I thought this mean Django detected an app named "users" in the root directory that is not registered in INSTALLED_APP. So, when I add "users" to INSTALLED_APP and remove "applications.users.apps.CustomUsersConfig", Django then detects the model in "applications/users". However, I do not have "users" app in the project root.

Any help or clue to this problem would be very appreciated.

Comment: Ok, I was crawling through in the source for django/db/models/base.py and somehow the project started working fine. What I did was just addings some print statements to the part where it checks the RunTimeError. I printed "getattr(meta, 'app_label', None)" and after I tried running the project several times It somehow started working without the error. Does this mean Django have some kind of cache feature that saves the previous state, which was the cause of this problem? Although I got it working, I appreciate more info about the cause of this issue.

Comment: Also, from the print statement, app(module) named "users" was loaded after the system check was ran.

Answer (score 4):

I got this error by having a similar setup with another app next to my users app. I imported the User model with:

```
from users.model import User
```

and fixed it with doing:

```
from applications.users.model import User
```